# releasing UIViewController subclasses does not actually free up memory

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, memory-management

I have a `UINavigationController` object (named `LoginNav`) which consists of `ViewController1` & `ViewController2`, my iPad app starts by loading a `UISplitViewController` subclass (named `mainSplitViewController`) and then presenting `LoginNav` modally on top of it (this is by the way done in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of AppDelegate like this:

`[self.mainSplitViewController presentModalViewController:LoginNav animated:YES];`).

Once `ViewController1` is shown, I tap a `UIButton` in it to push `ViewController2`, when I finish working in `ViewController2` I tap a `UIButton` in it to call `[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` to dismiss `LoginNav` with both of its view controllers and show `mainSplitViewController's` contents.

There is a `dealloc` method in both `ViewController1` & `ViewController2` with `NSLog` statement in each one, once `loginNav` is dismissed, the `NSLogs` never get fired, but doing `[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] release];` & `[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] release];` right after `[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` fires both `NSLogs`.

I commented out the above two release statements, then I launched the `Allocations` instrument, and launched the app again and pushed `ViewController2` then dismissed `loginNav` as described above, and looked at `Live Bytes` column (All Allocations value ) it was `6.9 MB` right after the dismissal of `loginNav`, then I did this step again but in this case using the two release statements, I got exactly a `6.9 MB` value on `Live Bytes` column.

Two Questions:

1) why do not the `dealloc` methods of `ViewController1` & `ViewController2` never get fired after the dismissal of the navigation controller `LoginNav` that holds them ? and is it correct to do the above two release statements to release these view controllers ?

2) why releasing `ViewController1` & `ViewController2` does not free up memory ?

p.s. there is no single variable (or `IBOutlet)` being held in memory in both `ViewController1` & `ViewController2`, everything is released in both of them.

Comment: So you subclasses a UINavigationController (why?) and you put 2 UIViewControllers inside of it (why?)?

Comment: i do not subclass UINavigationController, I have updated the question above, replaced the word (subclass) by (object).

Comment: Rather than explain bits of your code verbosely it might be easier for us to understand your problem if you posted a contiguous block of code.

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of issues are nearly impossible to troubleshoot without seeing all your code. When you manage memory manually, there are multiple areas that you can go wrong. For example the following code will leak:

```
- (void)didSelectSomethingInViewControllerOne
{
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
}
```

In this case you have allocated the object and thus have ownership of it. Then the nav controller takes ownership of it. When you pop the controller from the navigation stack, the navigation controller relinquishes ownership of it, but you never did, so it still has a retain count of 1 and won't get deallocated.

Relinquishing ownership of the controllers later in your code (like after dismissing the modal view) is a bad idea. It makes it difficult to analyze ownership when your releases are all over the place. As soon as the navigation controller has ownership you can release the object you allocated, as you do not intend to use it in the future:

```
- (void)didSelectSomethingInViewControllerOne
{
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
    [vc2 release];
}
```

The situation above can have nothing to do with your problem. Your problem may reside in many different areas. Which is why troubleshooting memory management problems is difficult. Without seeing source code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider transitioning your project to ARC:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: the problem in ARC is that it works only on IOS 5+ ... and my project runs on both 4 and 5 ...

Comment: @JAHelia ARC works with iOS 4 if you use Xcode 4.2. Quoted from the [Transitioning to ARC release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html): "ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for Mac OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5. Weak references are not supported in Mac OS X v10.6 and iOS 4."

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you might have fallen foul of is a retained property (such as a delegate) in your LoginNav.